# Settings to take advantage of unused RAM

Tags: ram

An older (2011) 1.7Ghz SSD machine is outfitted with 16.04 & 8GB of RAM.  In general performance is OK, however, with Firefox it is slow.  More often than not, less than 50% of RAM is in use.

Is there any setting or techniques to improve speed?  Firefox responsiveness?  Thank you

```
user@host:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218M [NVS 3100M] (rev a2)
    DeviceName: 0
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GT218M [NVS 3100M]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia

user@host:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        2.7G        1.2G        135M        3.8G        4.5G
Swap:          7.9G         15M        7.9G

user@host:~$ swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda5                               partition   8311804 16352   -1

user@host:~$ dpkg -l intel-microcode | grep ii
ii  intel-microcode 3.20151106.1 amd64        Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs
```

CPU Details:

```
user@host:~$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 30
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU       Q 740  @ 1.73GHz
Stepping:              5
CPU MHz:               933.000
CPU max MHz:           1734.0000
CPU min MHz:           933.0000
BogoMIPS:              3457.66
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid dtherm ida
```

[Firefox/Profile on RAM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Firefox/Profile_on_RAM)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: This is not a RAM issue. Web page rendering is heave for CPU and GPU.

Comment: show me `free -h` and `swapon -s` and `dpkg -l intel-microcode | grep ii`. What processor do you have?

Comment: @heynnema: lscpu results are posted (along with the 3 requested commands).  Is that sufficient to answer the processor question?  Looking forward to reading your response

Comment: @gatorback thanks for the info! It all looks good to me. Do you find that Firefox works better after you've just booted the machine, and gets slower after the machine has been up for a while?

Comment: @heynnema:  Any detailed comments regarding the data posted is appreciated (I would like to learn what parameters you are evaluating and what their nominal range should be).  No, Firefox is not slower after it machine reaches steady state.  It seems that Firefox is slow because of CPU cycles or lack thereof.   Seems that a quadcore CPU does not buy much in terms of Firefox performance

Comment: I use `free -h` to look at the total sizes of ram and swap, `swapon -s` to see if it's partition or file based swap, and that it's working, `dpkg` to see if a specific software package is installed. Show me `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Also, install this addon in FF https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-on-compatibility-reporter/?src=api, open your add-ons settings page, disable all extensions that are not "multiprocess" aware, restart FF, and see if it works better/worse.

Comment: If you have an answer, post it as one, do not edit it into the question.